# NoClassDefFoundError on com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzw

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-performance

Received numbers of crash report from Firebase Crashlytics. It is related to firebase-perf I think.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzw
   at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.start(Unknown Source:44)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zze.onActivityStarted(Unknown Source:48)
   at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:205)
   at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1150)
```

Already using the newest version of Firebase and Google Play Services.

It does not crash on devices in Firebase Test Lab. But ~1% of user facing this problem.

Is it related to absent of GMS Core? If so, how to handle it properly, not causing crash on those devices?

--- Update ---

project build.gradle

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha04'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App build.gradle

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MASKED"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode "MASKED"
        versionName "MASKED"
        resConfigs "en"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        textReport true
        textOutput 'stdout'
        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'

}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add the content for both of your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: What is the API level of the devices on which the exception occurs? I am seeing this problem on API 28.

Comment: Different API level facing this problem. From Android 5.1.1 to Android 8. But mostly Android 6.

Comment: It's happening for me as well.

Comment: Hello! I'm from the Firebase Performance Monitoring team. I have a couple questions to help us figure out where this bug is.

1. Do you see this problem when running on android studio or on production apps via crashlytics? 

2. If it's crashlytics, do you use Android App Bundles (https://developer.android.com/platform/technology/app-bundle/)

Comment: @mike_haney
1. I cannot reproduce it in my env. Those error are received from Crashlytics.
2. Both APK and AAB release will have similar crash report.

Comment: @mike_haney: I was seeing the problem both with release builds (via Crashlytics) and debug builds.  I don't use App Bundles.  The problem resolved after I upgraded Android Studio to use Android Gradle Plugin `3.3.0-alpha08` and also upgraded to the [Aug 23 release](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) of the Firebase SDK. I also disabled R8 with `android.enableR8=false` and used Proguard for minification of release builds.  Not sure if all these changes were needed.

Comment: @mike_haney We're suffering from the same crashes

Comment: @mike_haney I am getting crashes from both Production and debug, it happens every-time I open the app. It started when I updated com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0 I am rolling back to 16.0.0. The stacktrace points at a line that has a logEvent method from FirebaseAnalytics and in debug build says that I have not called FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) even if I explicitly called from my Application class.

Comment: @mike_haney I have a device in hands and I can reproduce the error on it with all of my apps

Comment: Be sure to let @Tejas know in the below answer, he's the engineer resolving these issues

Answer (score 9):

Firebase support has just confirmed me this is a bug. They are working on this right now (although they weren't able to reproduce it yet). So we should expect this to be fixed in a future Firebase release.

Comment: Did Firebase Support suggest anything to work around the problem?  I haven't been able to figure out what library or tool downgrade I need to do to get back to a working configuration.

Comment: They didn't say. I'll ask.

Comment: after I've upgraded com.google.firebase:firebase-perf to 16.1.0 my users started experiencing crashes as well, just gonna roll back to 16.0.0

Comment: @niqueco Can we get a link to the bug report?

Comment: @MinasMina There's no bug report. I had a conversation with Firebase support. They confirmed the issue but they could not reproduce it. Yesterday I got the last email saying that as they still can't reproduce it locally they will close my report and "monitor" the situation. (?)

Comment: I am facing the very same thing. The version is 16.1.0. To reproduce, launch the app and wait 30 minutes. The app will never be launched again.

Answer (score 6):

**Update: Please update to Firebase Performance Version 16.2.5 to solve this issue.**

Comment: Build a new version without Multidex. Let see if it help.
BTW, Multidex w/ AndroidX is having a much slower cold starts......

Comment: @niqueco Did you face problem 1 or problem 2?

Comment: Update: Issue seems gone after removing multidex.

Comment: @Tejas Problem 1. I got lots of crashes in Crashlytics in my app (no multidex) untill I downgraded firebase-perf.

Comment: @niqueco Can you share device/OS combos that this crash happens on?

Comment: @Tejas Yes...

--

Moto G (2nd gen) - Android 6.0 ;
Galaxy Note 4 - Android 6.0.1 ;
Galaxy S5 mini - Android 6.0.1 ;
Galaxy S5 Neo - Android 6.0.1

--

I thought there were non Android 6 errors, but I can't find them now.

Comment: We're seeing lots of the `NoClassDefFoundError` in Crashlytics and Play crash reports, so far across Android 5 and 6 versions. @Tejas, we tried a proguard change (https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/pull/2548/files) and that didn't help. The project is open source if that can help (https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/issues/2542). Can't reproduce locally so disabling the lib for now.

Comment: Device manufacturers: 33% samsung, 23% Xiaomi, 20% LENOVO, 17% ZTE 7% Other. Also seeing a Huawei in a different report of the same crash (seems it can happen from different activities) so I don't think it's related to device.

Comment: I can reproduce the error!!! I have a device in my hands right now and I can reproduce it wherever I want

Comment: @Tejas Has this been fixed? There's a 16.1.2 release, but no release notes has been posted. Should I upgrade? Thanks.

Comment: @niqueco. No it is not fixed. I can reproduce the error on version 16.1.2 as well

Comment: @everyone - Please try using version 16.2.0 of the firebase performance SDK - we've added a potential fix to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tejas This still occurs on 16.2.0. Using com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5

Comment: @LukeBrandonFarrell Would you be able to share the stacktrace of the issue? (Ideally uploaded to a github gist or a pastebin)

Comment: @Tejas any update on this bug? Looks like we're now on 16.2.3 of firebase-perf. Have there been any fixes?

Comment: We've identified the problem and are working on a fix - I'll update the answer once we're able to ship it!

Comment: @user1809913 Please update to version 16.2.4 of firebase performance to fix this issue.