# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzw

Tags: android, firebase, noclassdeffounderror

Getting this Error on app launch.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzw
>          at com.google.firebase.perf.metrics.Trace.start(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zze.onActivityStarted(Unknown
>   Source)
>          at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityStarted(Application.java:205)
>          at android.app.Activity.onStart(Activity.java:1156)
>          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
>          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1268)
>          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6333)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2542)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2671)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1501)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5774)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

//

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
// Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
// keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")

// Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()

// Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.9"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

//Signing configurations for build variants "release"
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

 compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

Comment: can you post code ?

Comment: posted above...

Comment: This is happening to me too. Report it as a Firebase bug (as I did) so that they pay attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError on com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-perf.zzw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51933637/noclassdeffounderror-on-com-google-android-gms-internal-firebase-perf-zzw)

Comment: @niqueco said i downgraded firebase pref to 16.0.0 know its working fine

Answer (score 5):

**Firebase-crash version** and **firebase-perf version** must be lesser than or equal to the **Firebase-core version** so In your code just change the **Firebase-crash:16.0.1 version to  Firebase-crash:16.0.0** and **firebase-perf:16.1.0 version to firebase-perf:16.0.0** Because your's firebase-core version is 16.0.1

```
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'
```

Comment: This is basic things in Android. The Above person face NoClassDefFoundError  . This Error shows one of the main reason is version mismatched. **ref** [ https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android ]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, although Siva Kumar's solution worked, what also worked for me was to use the latest google-services library on your **project** *build.gradle* :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the other solutions worked. Very frustrating, the application didn't even start.
Finally I removed Performance Monitoring:

```
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2'
```

Comment: For me also, same problem, app not starting, I tried lot of combinations. I was not updated google-services json file. I updated still the problem happens. Finally removed the firebase performance monitoring "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.1.2" package and all started working fine. I was using old version (16.0.0) of this package and it was working fine, in the latest package, things are not working as expected. Thanks @tsig

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved in two steps:

- First, I updated all my Firebase dependencies in build.gradle (app) to their latest versions. *Simply update every highlighted Firebase dependency*.
- Update your google-services library on your build.gradle (project) to the latest version. You can also use the warning-highlight of android studio to guide you.

  ```
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0' // this is the latest as at July, 2019
  }
  ```

Everything should work fine after this.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!

Answer (score -3):

As per the pre-requisites documentation on Firebase - Performance Monitoring documentation about android:

> Before you begin, you need a few things set up in your environment:
>
> ```
> A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and Google Play services 16.1.0 or higher
> The Google Play services SDK from the Google Repository, available in the Android SDK Manager
> The latest version of Android Studio, version 2.2 or higher
> ```

This link explains in details for the setup.

[Firebase Performance Monitoring Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android)

Moreover, Alex has mentioned about the way we can bring in the latest google services in build cycle by upgrading the dependency mentioned in the gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```