# Missing file in apk unity build

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build my apk but it keeps crashing on load and I get this error on android.

It seems I am missing something called the zzef file? But I am not sure what it is.

```
12-12 10:38:59.743 21242-21242/com.TrisAviorEntertainment.WarOfTheOrigin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.TrisAviorEntertainment.WarOfTheOrigin, PID: 21242
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzef
        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeg.zzdk(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzj.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:43)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy$$Lambda$1.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:54)
        at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:26)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:34)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:82)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:761)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:359)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:324)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:310)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1716)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1685)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5555)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5090)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
12-12 10:38:59.773 21242-21259/com.TrisAviorEntertainment.WarOfTheOrigin E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzdl;: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzy.getHandler(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is usually caused by a mismatch between Firebase versions. Please post your app-level `build.gradle` here, this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941007/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-internal