# Android Gradle: All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Performance SDK. It occurs this conflict on this line (marked red line by Analysis) and crash after launch the app:

```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

***All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.1.0, 17.0.5, 17.0.3, 17.0.1, 16.3.0, 16.2.3, 16.2.1, 16.1.0, 16.0.7, 16.0.3, 16.0.1, 16.0.0.***

I've searched and tried the related questions/answers of this similar title but no one can work.

The dependencies are listed below. Before I used all version 11.8.0 working well. Performance SDK wants me to use firebase-perf:16.2.3 and it start this problem. Even though I modify all of them to 16.x.x, it still con't be fixed. I wonder whether it needs all of them in all the same subversion? But It can't be done for I've tried many of them lack a lot of subversions. For example if using all version 16.0.0, Some of them will occur "Failed to resolve:...".

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
```

build.gradle(Project: xxxx)

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'   //for crashlytics
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'  //for performance
}
```

Comment: Pelase add the entire content of your build.gradle file. Please also add the other one.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the Play services plugin in the top level gradle file.  Check that *everything* is up to date according to the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, everything is up to date, except below two. But even I changed them up to date to 17.1.3, this error is still there.
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'

Comment: Your play services plugin is WAY out of date. Latest is 4.2.0. You have 3.0.0. you're also list it a second time with another old version 4.0.2.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, Thanks! I remove the necessary classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'. The same error is still there.
And if I use 4.2.0, some other error appears as below. It seems not related with the original error.

Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/strict-version-matcher-plugin/1.1.0/strict-version-matcher-plugin-1.1.0.pom...

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the google maven repo added to your buildscript.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, the google maven has been added before for firebase crashlytics. It's not listed in above code for it's obviously unrelated.

Comment: I'm talking about the google maven *repository*, not the classpath dependency.  You should probably re-read the setup documentation and check that you've added everything required.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, maven were added before in build.gradle(Project:).        
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'    //for crashlytics
        }
    }
---
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Doug Stevenson, I've tried a solution as the answer below, though I don't know why. Maybe you can explain for us.

Comment: I've never had to do what your answer is suggesting, nor have I ever heard of that being done.  Without seeing your entire build.gradle files, it's not really possible to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot of hours, it happens to work on the following modifications.
Especially the "(", ")" are needed for 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0', otherwise the conflict will not disappear!

```
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0')

compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'){exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"}
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:16.0.1'){exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"}
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'){exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"}
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'){exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'  //if using 16.2.3, sometime the app crashes as soon as it starts. 
                                                       //Below post reported that some other bug from firebase-perf:16.1.0
                                                         //https://stackoverflow.com/a/51967966/8046317
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio: once the Gradle file is opened you should be able to see that some libraries are marked in yellow, if you hover the mouse over them a popup shows which are the latest version so you can start by replacing all of them with the latest version. After that cleaning and rebuilding the project could help.

Comment: all the libraries, which are marked yellow, are corrected in above attached code, except below tow lines. But even I update these two line up to date, the problem is still there. 

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'

Comment: Could you add the exact message that you receive now after updating all the versions? I'm using in a project those: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2' and 'implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6' and there are no conflicts. Maybe you don't need both ads libraries...

Comment: the message is just on the original question:

It occurs this error on this line (marked red by analysis):

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 17.1.0, 17.0.5, 17.0.3, 17.0.1, 16.3.0, 16.2.3, 16.2.1, 16.1.0, 16.0.7, 16.0.3, 16.0.1, 16.0.0.